# Electrical code for adding an outlet that is "full"

Tags: electrical

I've added an outlet in the past to another circuit when the outlet had a space to "jump" wires off to another outlet. But the outlet that I'd like to use as a source to add another outlet already appears to have another outlet pulling from it. IE all four slots are full.

I'm assuming that I'm out of luck in terms of adding another outlet to this, but I am curious if I can create a pigtail to add on top of this outlet. The concern of course is this following electrical code? and if I'm creating a potential fire hazard.

Comment: It's _very_ good that you're asking this question before just doing! Please [edit] to include pictures of the existing wiring and of the wires in the box. Please also look in the box to see if you can find any writing stamped into it. The main thing you're going to run into is a rule called "box fill" - if the box gets too full, you can generate excessive heat and start a fire.

Comment: Pig tails usually recommended, but it depend on the size of the box if it is big enough for another set of wires

Comment: That is a decent point, with the two sets of wires coming into the box, it is a bit cramped. It's possible with the pigtails that I can free up some space, but admittedly not a ton.

Comment: "all four slots full" Is that all four holes per side or ie four cables? #12 or @14?

Answer (score 3):

By "all 4", I assume you mean:

- Top and bottom screws on one side have black hot wires
- Top and bottom screws on the other side have white neutral wires

There are two options. Both require first running the new cable between this box and the new box.

- Pigtails

Connect the existing two black wires, the new black wire and a short (~ 6") pigtail black wire (14 AWG or 12 AWG for 15A circuit, 12 AWG for 20A circuit) to a wire nut or a Wago style connector. Connect the other end of the pigtail to one of the screws on the receptacle. Tighten the other screw down.

Repeat for white neutral.

- Replace with a better receptacle

There is a better type of receptacle, typically listed as Commercial Grade or with a term such as "screw to clamp". This lets you put two wires straight in (instead of making a hook for one wire) underneath a piece of metal under the screw. That is easier than making the usual hooks, and since you get two wires per screw you can have 4 wires per side, and you only need three wires per side.

Comment: Yes exactly as you describe it.
Top and bottom screws on one side have black hot wires, top and bottom screw on the other side have white neutral wires.

Ok, so it sounds like I can connect the two black wires into a wago with one wire coming out to the outlet itself. And repeat for the white wires. 

Then I can wire the other outlet to the now empty screws on the outlet?

Comment: @Jamg: You're better off using the Wago for all connections and leaving the second set of screws on the outlet empty (you'll use two 4-bay Wagos, one for black and one for white).  If you did use all screws (perhaps you only have 3-bay Wagos), there'd be no reason to switch which daisychain is connected to them.

Comment: @BenVoigt or use 6 hole purple 773-166 wagos

Comment: @NoSparksPlease: Those don't look anywhere near as good as a levered Wago (although still probably better than the average backstab, OP has been using screws, not backstabs)

Comment: For novices learning new tricks the lever ones are more appropriate.    Easier to fix mistakes, not just wiring mistakes but replacing or upgrading poor product choices and building things incrementally as you learn.

Comment: @FreeMan This additional outlet has to be *somewhere* so it needs a cable going to it. I'm not addressing all the details of that - how to run cable, clamps, etc. and *only* discussing the actual connection issue.